# List some sites for Free C# video podcasts

Tags: c#

Can someone list a few sites where I can find some video podcasts related to C#? (Free ones ofcourse).

The only one I know is dnrtv.com.

Thanks

Edit:The list built so far based on my search and your answers put together....Please continue to add more ...Thanks

1. http://www.dnrtv.com
2. http://www.ScreenCastADay.com
3. http://www.videos.gridviewguy.com/VideoCategories.aspx
4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb798022.aspx?wt.slv=TopSectionSee
5. http://www.dimecasts.net/
6. http://www.learncsharp.com/FreeVideos/
7. http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/ARCast_with_Ron_Jacobs/
8. http://www.intelligentedu.com/blogs/post/best_new_training_sites/3710/top-19-c-tutorial-videos-on-youtube
9. http://www.free-ebook-download.net/video-training/2894-c-complete-video-tutorials.html
10. http://knowfree.net/2006/12/03/visual-c-video-tutorial.kf
11. http://highoncoding.com/Categories/22_Videos.aspx
12. http://windowsclient.net/learn
13. http://www.asp.net/learn/
14. http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2007/05/10/9322.aspx

Comment: Pleased note that the previously asked questions in stackoverflow such as this... "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423/best-net-podcasts/393209#393209" have answers related to Audio Podcasts. My question here is about video podcasting sites. Hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 6):

[channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com)  ( all sorts of videos )

[MSDN How Do I Videos for C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb798022.aspx?wt.slv=TopSectionSee) ( only c# related )

Answer (score 6):

Suprised to see that [DimeCasts](http://www.dimecasts.net/) hasn't been mentioned already - short (around 10 minutes), focused and high quality. Recommended.

Comment: http://www.dimecasts.net/ is very focused & good site. but the tagging for c# is missing & the content is very less. Like in advance concepts there are only 8 videos. Moreover the videos are not updated on a regular basis which is another disadvantage...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the another one.

http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/

You can have great video for C# here.But its not free.

For free videos you can see following sites:
http://www.learncsharp.com/FreeVideos/

http://www.intelligentedu.com/blogs/post/best_new_training_sites/3710/top-19-c-tutorial-videos-on-youtube

http://www.free-ebook-download.net/video-training/2894-c-complete-video-tutorials.html

http://knowfree.net/2006/12/03/visual-c-video-tutorial.kf

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Forms and WPF:
http://windowsclient.net/

For ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC:
http://www.asp.net/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ScreenCastADay.com

Answer (score 0):

Not surprisingly this has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423/best-net-podcasts/393209#393209

In regards to video There was ArchCast.tv (now part of channel 9)

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/ARCast_with_Ron_Jacobs/