# Recommended books for Objective C

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to learn C and Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928833/how-to-learn-c-and-objective-c)

I'm looking for recommendations for good books targeting people who are new to Objective C.

Comment: Do you want to learn it for iPhone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Programming in Objective-C"* by Stephen Kochran (I think). It handles the language itself. You can try out all samples on OSX with XCode. It isn't really a book about iDevices Programming, but a book about the language itself.
Then again, to learn Objective-C on the Mac, try Aaron Hillegass' *"Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X"* and for iDevices programming, have a look at [pragprog.com](http://pragprog.com) they have a ton of really, really good books about iDevices programming and the several topics they can address. I started with Bill Dudneys *"iPhone SDK Development"* (I also attended one of his classes), teaches you the good stuff from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

If it's for iOS (iPhonePadPod), do yourself a favor and get [iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321773772). Get other books later when (if) you feel you need them.